# Why do I not see a comment button most times

Tags: support

I am not sure if this is right place to ask, but Why do I not see a comment button most of the times?

I have posted comments when I could, but when I needed to post one and do not see a way to do so [logged in, check] what do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least 50 reputation on each site to be able to [comment everywhere](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

You have 44 rep at the moment; one more (main site) upvote and you'll be there.

Comment: thanks Hugo. I visit many sites and will always remember this requirement.

Comment: Oh, right. Another thing I keep forgetting? Thanks Jasper, I did.